# How to set length of certificate serial number explicitly?

Tags: openssl, certificate

I am newbie to `openssl` and I am trying to create a end-device certificate (from command-line options). I want to set the length of the serial number (16 bytes) of the certificate. I read that `-set_serial` option can only be used for self-signed certificates. In my `openssl.cnf` file I have set `serial          = $dir/serial` and also created a `serial` file. For now I have specified 16 bytes (random number,hexadecimal) in this file and certificate created uses this. But, I wanted to know whether it is possible to use command-line parameter for the same? Are there any cli option like `set_serial`?
Also, how will the serial number set for new certificates next time? Should I replace the hexadecimal in `serial` file?